# Rounded angular numbers font used on 1960s college football jerseys

Tags: fonts, font-identification, numbering

Seeking to identify the number / digit font used on a number of old football jerseys from the 1960s.

These font was used by the University of Washington football team in the 1960s. There are many pictures of the 1960 and 1961 Rose Bowl where the Huskies are wearing this font.

[image: 1960 Rose Bowl]

The font can also be found on vintage jerseys available on eBay, for teams other than the Huskies.

Both of these jerseys are tagged "Spanjian Pasadena", which was the manufacturer. I'm unsure if this font is unique to Spanjain, or if other manufacturers used the same font.

[image: eBay yellow football jersey]

[image: 1960s UW Washington Football Jersey 32]

Traits include rounded and angular digits, very different from the typical "block" numbers of a football uniform. The "3" has an elongated lower arm.

UW / Nike created throwback uniforms in 2007 for the 1960 team, including the unique numbers:

[image: UW throwback 1960 uniforms]

I've searched on WhatTheFont and other tools listed in the FAQ, with no success.

I will work on finding examples of every numeral and update this question.

This font was also used by high school teams. [Eisenhower High School (Yakima, WA) yearbook](https://www.yakimaherald.com/sports/sports_watch/yesterdays-champions-best-bets-for-winning-a-state-football-title-before-the-playoffs/article_4d83146f-770b-5a62-9b39-ca03895247a3.html) for 1965:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like a "font" to me... but handcrafted for stitching. Someone drew a number for a pattern then the sewing pattern was used multiple times.

Comment: A similar font seems to have been used for the 1960 Oakland Raiders.

Comment: Used for the 2009 University of Chicago Maroons: https://www.flickr.com/photos/uchicagomagazine/3940580117/

Comment: 1990s/2000s era Reebok jersey: https://web.archive.org/web/20240129210647/https://www.ebay.com/itm/285675269176

Comment: ..... Someone drew a number for a pattern then the sewing pattern was used multiple times